# MVC view with two different models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view called `AccountManager` on this view I have a section to update your profile information and update your password.

Both functions require a different model. `ManageUserViewModel` and `ChangePasswordViewModel`.

On the `AccountManager` view, both sections are rendered via `@Html.Partial`.

When I try to display the page, I receive the following error: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WebUI.Models.ManageUserViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebUI.Models.ChangePasswordViewModel'."

How can I render both views without receiving this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc

Comment: I understand what a ViewModel is in MVC. That wasn't my question. My question is, how do you display a view with two different Models.

Comment: you put both models into a view model and on your view you use the model that pertains.  something like @Html.RenderPartial("_PartialName", Model.ChangePaswordViewModel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ViewModel:**

```
public class AccountManagerViewModel
{ 
    public ManageUserViewModel manageUserViewModel { get; set; }
    public ChangePasswordViewModel changePasswordViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

**The View:**

```
@model AccountManagerViewModel
/*HTML CODE*/
@Html.RenderPartial("_PartialChangePassword", Model.changePasswordViewModel)
@Html.RenderPartial("_PartialManageUser", Model.manageUserViewModel)
```

So you just play with the viewModels. Remember that they can have anything you need in the view. Let me know.